# Check code for saving textfield.text in a dictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSInteger field = textField.tag;
    userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
    if(field ==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
    [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FirstName"];

    }
    if(field ==2)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MiddleName"];


    }

    if(field ==3)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"LastName"];
    }

    if(field ==4)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Country"];
    }

    if(field ==5)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"State"];
    }

    if(field ==6)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"City"];
    }

    if(field ==7)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"DOB"];
    }




}



- (IBAction)saveAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {



    NSLog(@"the values stored in dictionary are %@",userDetailsDictionary);

}
```

Kindly check the above code.I am trying to save the text on every textfield of custom cell in dictionary on click of save button.But it actually stores the text entered on last textfield.Please tell why is so happening.I am a fresher and not able to understand this.

Comment: call this in `userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];` in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: I don't understand, it's missing context. Are each UITextField on different cells? Since it's a UITableView (or UICollectionView), the logic of `ZzzView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove this `userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];` in delegate method of `textFieldDidEndEditing` and add in `viewDidLoad`,

for e.g

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
  userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
}


 -(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{


    if(textField.tag ==1)
    {
        NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
    [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"FirstName"];

    }
    if(textField.tag ==2)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"MiddleName"];


    }

    if(textField.tag ==3)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"LastName"];
    }

    if(textField.tag ==4)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"Country"];
    }

    if(textField.tag ==5)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"State"];
    }

    if(textField.tag ==6)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"City"];
    }

    if(textField.tag ==7)
    {
          NSLog(@"cell1.userDetailTextField.text %@",textField.text);
        [userDetailsDictionary setObject:textField.text forKey:@"DOB"];
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others already pointed out, you should initialize your dictionary in `viewDidLoad` method and then just set values into that object. Also don't forget to declare your dict as a `strong` property.

I will just improve your code so that it is a bit more readable:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *userDetailsDictionary;    
@end

@implementation ViewController    

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
}    

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"cell%ld.userDetailTextField.text %@", (long)textField.tag, textField.text);
    switch (textField.tag) {
        case 1: _userDetailsDictionary[@"FirstName"] = textField.text; break;
        case 2: _userDetailsDictionary[@"MiddleName"] = textField.text; break;
        case 3: _userDetailsDictionary[@"LastName"] = textField.text; break;
        case 4: _userDetailsDictionary[@"Country"] = textField.text; break;
        case 5: _userDetailsDictionary[@"State"] = textField.text; break;
        case 6: _userDetailsDictionary[@"City"] = textField.text; break;
        case 7: _userDetailsDictionary[@"DOB"] = textField.text; break;
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

do in `viewdidload`

```
userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary  alloc] init];
```

Its due to the userdetaildictionry is been allocating each time you call finish editing.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are init the dictionary every time textFieldDidEndEditing is called.
move init to viewDidLoad method.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    userDetailsDictionary= [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```